# Why is my Flutter app writing to Realtime Database instead of Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Shouldn't this code below write a user document to the users collection?

Instead, it creates a object in my Realtime Database

What am I missing?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  final CollectionReference usersCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future updateUserData(String analysisStatus, String cpf, String email,
      String name, String phone) async {
    return await usersCollection.doc(this.uid).set({
      'analysisStatus': analysisStatus,
      'cpf': cpf,
      'email': email,
      'name': name,
      'phone': phone
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you're observing that's different than what you expect.  From what you show here, there is no access to Realtime Database at all.  There's not enough information here to explain what you're observing.

Comment: I solved it and found a curious thing at same time. My Cloud Firestore security rules where denying access to it, so, as I already had my user authenticated at Firebase, it wrote the document to Realtime Database instead.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it and found a curious thing at same time. My Cloud Firestore security rules where denying access to it, so, as I already had my user authenticated at Firebase, it wrote the document to Realtime Database instead.